# exec from Java: looking up appropriate script executors

Tags: java, bash, powershell, process, exec

We're currently writing a java application that involves letting a user execute another program from withen ours. This other program could be another executable, or a script, and could take any number of command line parameters. We've built a GUI to do this and, in the basic functional case, it works.

We're using apache exec to do this, though at this point I'm not actually sure what value its giving us.

The problem I'm having is with known script file types.

If you open powershell and type `./myVisualBasicScript.vbs` it will, internally, translate that into the command something like `wscript.exe ./myVisualBasicScript.vbs`. Similarly, iirc, in bash if you type `./someTCShellScript.tcsh`, it will invoke that script under tcshell.

I'm wondering if there's a library that will provide this mapping for me. Ideally this library is one where I could do something like

```
CommandLine cmd = new com.awesome.library.CommandLine(
    pathToExecutableOrScript,
    args
);

cmd.execute();
```

It would be nice if such a library sported watchdogs and timeouts and signal handling etc, but the main feature I'm looking for is some kind of method to map from file types (preferably using both extensions and meta properties) to the executable that runs them.

I've been building a map inside our application, and I'm at least aware of javas `java.awt.Desktop.open()` method, which almost does this job for me, though its more tailored toward GUI'd applications. I'm not sure if it has the facilities to capture standard in, out, and error, or have watchdogs and timeouts, etc.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Flagged: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: ... except if there is only on library in existence that does it? If we're talking about XStream vs GSon you'd be right, but this isn't asking for one library in a set of libraries, I'm asking about _the existence_ of such a library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)  to do so

```
// Create ProcessBuilder.
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
// Use command "notepad.exe" and open the file.
p.command("notepad.exe", "C:\\file.txt");
p.start();
```

Or

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: and `exec("sh", "bashScript")` and `exec("powershell", "script.ps1")` and `exec("ansys", "apdlScript.m")` and `exec("matlab", "matlabscript.m")` and `exec("????", "scripItThatIDontKnowAbout.funnyExt")`... and on and on. I do not have the skill or time as a developer to build the complete list of scripting languages and their executors. I would much rather leverage a library, which itself leverges things like the windows file-extension registry and similar linux facilities to execute these files.

Comment: The idea of invoking different scripts from Java program seems a bit odd. It is usually the other way around, as Java program should run in different environments. Is it a mandatory to do it that way? Anyway I do not know such library you need. But I was thinking to create a batch file which will invoke each supported script type and just call it from Java.

Comment: It is an unavoidable business requirement that we have this strategy. The idea of pushing this problem into a scripting language is an interesting (and should've been obvious to me) idea.